# How can properly test a class method using Rails and RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Testing class methods with Spec

Hi,

I have just started working with Rails and RSpec tests. I need to develop a feature for an existing system, so I decided to start using Behavior Driven Development. I set up the RSpec for Rails by installing the following gems:

```
group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "capybara", ">= 2.15"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
  gem "httparty", "~> 0.18.1"
end
```

At the Specs folder, I created services folder, then created test file: santander_payslip_controller.rb.

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'payslip'

describe Payslip, type: :service do

    describe ".authenticate" do
      santander = Payslip::Santander.new "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx"
      context "given the client_id and client_secret" do
      
        it "fails without the digital certificate" do
          expect(santander.authenticate()).not_to eql('201')
        end
      
      end
    
    end

end
```

I need to test a class method that will validate if the Santander API is able to perform authentication on class authenticate method. The class containing the method that needs to be tested is under a method that includes the HTTParty gem.

```
module Payslip  

  class Santander
    include HTTParty
    
    def initialize(client_id, client_secret, account_id)
      @client_id = client_id
      @client_secret = client_secret
      @account_id = account_id
      @base_uri = Rails.configuration.santander_base_uri
    end

    def authenticate()
      url = @base_uri + '/token'
      params = {
        "client_id" => @client_id,
        "client_secret" => @client_secret,
        "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
      }
      payload = {body: params}
      response = post(url, payload).symbolize_key
      response.code
    end

end
```

Whenever I run the rspec command to perform tests, I see ruby complaining about not recognizing post method (HTTParty).

```
F

Failures:

  1) Payslip.authenticate given the client_id and client_secret fails without the digital certificate
     Failure/Error: response = post(url, payload).symbolize_key

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for #<Payslip::Santander:0x0000000108e51330>
      ./app/services/payslip.rb:23:in `authenticate'
      ./spec/services/santander_payslip_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01818 seconds (files took 3.95 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/services/santander_payslip_controller_spec.rb:10 # Payslip.authenticate given the client_id and client_secret fails without the digital certificate
```

Can you help pointing out what I could be doing wrong either in Ruby, RSpec or possibly Rails configurations?

For reference, I am using Rails 6.1, Ruby 2.6.3, and RSpec 3.12

I wish I could understand how to properly configure RSpec and make it to understand the HTTParty methods used by my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change this `post(url, payload)` to `self.class.post(url,payload)` in the `Payslip::Santander#authenticate` method.

This has nothing to do with the RSpec test it is just how `HTTParty` is intended to work. When you `include HTTParty` it in turn calls `extend ClassMethods` as part of the `Module#included` hook. The `#post` method is defined in the `HTTParty::ClassMethods` module.

- [HTTParty::included](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L26)
- [HTTParty::ClassMethods#post](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L541)

Comment: You're right. I thought I had messed out my RSpec & Rails configuration, but it was just another rookie mistake. Thanks!